# Error in Godot 4.2.1. Move and Slide Error

Tags: gdscript

The error is at line 72, the error says:
Line 72:Too many arguments for "move_and_slide()" call. Expected at most 0 but received 5.
Line 72:Value of type "bool" cannot be assigned to a variable of type "Vector3".

i'm tryng to use "move_and_slide" in my code and it doesn't work

here is the code:

```
extends CharacterBody3D

const MOUSE_SENSITIVITY = 0.1

@onready var camera = $CamRoot/Camera

# Movement
var current_vel = Vector3.ZERO
var dir = Vector3.ZERO

const SPEED = 10
const SPRINT_SPEED = 20
const ACCEL = 15.0

# Jump
const GRAVITY = -40.0
const JUMP_SPEED = 15
var jump_counter = 0
const AIR_ACCEL = 9.0



func _ready():
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)



func _process(delta):
    window_activity()



func _physics_process(delta):
    
    # Get the input directions
    dir = Vector3.ZERO
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("forward"):
        dir -= camera.global_transform.basis.z
    if Input.is_action_pressed("backward"):
        dir += camera.global_transform.basis.z
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        dir += camera.global_transform.basis.x
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        dir -= camera.global_transform.basis.x
    
    # Normalizing the input directions
    dir = dir.normalized()
    
    # Apply gravity
    velocity.y += GRAVITY * delta
    
    if is_on_floor():
        jump_counter = 0
    
    # Jump
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and jump_counter < 2:
        jump_counter += 1
        velocity.y = JUMP_SPEED
    
    # Set speed and target velocity
    var speed = SPRINT_SPEED if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint") else SPEED
    var target_vel = dir * speed
    
    # Smooth out the player's movement
    var accel = ACCEL if is_on_floor() else AIR_ACCEL
    current_vel = current_vel.linear_interpolate(target_vel, accel * delta)
    
    velocity.x = current_vel.x
    velocity.z = current_vel.z
    
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP, true, 4, deg_to_rad(45))



func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        # Rotates the view vertically
        $CamRoot.rotate_x(deg_to_rad(event.relative.y * MOUSE_SENSITIVITY * -1))
        $CamRoot.rotation_degrees.x = clamp($CamRoot.rotation_degrees.x, -75, 75)
        
        # Rotates the view horizontally
        self.rotate_y(deg_to_rad(event.relative.x * MOUSE_SENSITIVITY * -1))



# To show/hide the cursor
func window_activity():
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_cancel"):
        if Input.get_mouse_mode() == Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED:
            Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE)
        else:
            Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)
```

Thank you!

```
                                                                                    _
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the godot docs and you see why it is not working:

[Godot Docs CharacterBody3D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_characterbody3d.html#class-characterbody3d-method-move-and-slide)

It says:

> Returns true if the body collided, otherwise, returns false

move_and_slide returns a boolean not a Vector3D (as the error states), so you can't set the velocity property of the characterbody to a bool.